# Why do $\theta$ and $\theta+1$ disappear when differentiating $n\theta\ln(k)-(\theta+1)\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(y_i)$ with respect to $\theta$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a maximum likelihood estimation problem to solve for $ \theta $.

The derivative of
$$ l ( \theta ) = n \ln ( \theta ) + n \theta \ln ( k ) - ( \theta + 1 ) \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ n \ln ( y _ i ) $$
is
$$ l ' ( \theta ) = \frac n \theta + n \ln ( k ) - \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ n \ln ( y _ i ) \text . $$
I'm wondering:

1. Why $ \theta + 1 $ disappears from $ ( \theta + 1 ) \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ n \ln ( y _ i ) $?
2. Why $ \theta $ disappears from $ n \theta \ln ( k ) $?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are differentiating with respect to $\theta$ then $n\ln(k)$ is treated like a constant

Comment: You fail to include the entire question.  It looks like this is the derivative with respect to $\theta$, which in product rule, will be 1.

Comment: $\frac{d}{d\theta}c\theta=c$, where $c$ is some constant.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Those expressions don't "disappear", they become $1$ ... because $1$ is the derivative of $\theta$ with respect to $\theta$.

Comment: thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1.\;\quad \frac{d}{d\theta} \left( (\theta+1) \sum \ln(y)\right) =\frac{d}{d\theta} \left( \theta \sum \ln y + \sum \ln y\right) = \sum \ln y.$$

To see this more easily, consider $\sum \ln y = x$. Differentiating $\theta x$ with respect to $\theta$ leaves you with $x$.

A similar idea can be used for your second question, taking $n\ln{k}$ to be a constant.

Hope this helps

Comment: Many thanks, that makes it clearer